# generate RDF document From OWL file

Tags: semantics, rdf, owl

is there any tool that can generate RDF document from OWL file ?

Answer (score 1):

Jena (http://jena.sourceforge.net/ ) will do this.
Also look at OWLAPI (http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/ ) though personally I find it very awkward

Comment: Jena and the OWL api are designed to do two different things - Jena is RDF-centric and the OWL-API, well, OWL centric. The OWL API is extremely close to OWL's syntax and very powerful. I agree that there are some idiosyncrasies, but once one has come to terms with them, it's rewarding to use.